# php geoip not working on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, php, ubuntu-18.04, vestacp

I can't get the GeoIP PHP extension working on Ubuntu 18.04 with PHP 7.2

i have intalled it by the cli: `sudo apt-get install -y php7.2-geoip`

Its enabled in system but not working:

```
php7.2 -i | grep geoip
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-geoip.ini,
geoip
geoip support => enabled
geoip extension version => 1.1.1
geoip library version => 1006012
geoip.custom_directory => no value => no value
```

testing with the following php code:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE'];
```

but the GEOIP module is not working

Comment: Do you have some reason to believe that code should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are mixing up two things. You install the geoip extension for PHP. However, `$_SERVER['GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE']` is populated by Apache mod_geoip module.

Install Apache module

```
sudo apt install -y libapache2-mod-geoip
```

Modify the file /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/geoip.conf and remove the # in front of GeoIPDBFile - and set GeoIPENable to `On`:

```
  GeoIPEnable On
  GeoIPDBFile /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat
```

Save the file, restart apache: `apache2ctl restart`

Now you will have `$_SERVER['GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE']` available.

Comment: Hi, @frands-hansen , its showing the country code, but the problem is only showing same country even from other location IP, showing only Server IP's country code "CA"

Comment: Do you have some sort of reverse proxy in front of your apache?    Please try echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] and GEOIP_ADDR - does that show the IP address of the connecting client properly?

Comment: yes I have Nginx, and this $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] - Its displaying IP address of the client properly. but not correct country, my ip country is CA and its displaying FR?